# execution time of PowerShell script vastly differs between first and second run

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell

I'm facing something really strange when executing a little PowerShell script that fetches some information of a local Oralce DB and put the results into objects. The first execution of this scipt takes about 30 seconds, consecutive executions just as much as 2 seconds!

Does anybody have an explanation for this? (is it caching in the Oracle-DB? / any way to figure out what is causing the speed burst on the second run?)

```
function Get-SQLConnection 
{
    Add-Type -Path $(Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "libs/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll")
    $connectionString = 'User Id=FOO;Password=BAR;Data Source=TNSCONNID'
    return New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connectionString)
}

function Get-SQLIssueQuery($version) 
{
    $version = $version.ToString()
    return "SELECT ...
            FROM ... WHERE $version ..."
}

function Get-IssuesForVersion($dbconn, $version) 
{
    Write-Verbose "Get-IssuesForVersion $($version.ToString())..."
    $issues = @{}
    $command=$dbconn.CreateCommand()
    $command.CommandText=$(Get-SQLIssueQuery $version)
    $reader=$command.ExecuteReader()

    while ($reader.Read()) {
        $text = $reader[0]
        [int]$key = $reader[2].Split("-")[1]
        $type = $reader[6]
        ...
        $issues[$key] = [Issue]::new($key, $type, ...)
    }
    Write-KSDetail "Get-IssuesForVersion '$($version.ToString())' returned $($issues.Count) issues..."
    return $issues
}

$timestart = $(Get-Date)
$conn = Get-SQLConnection
$conn.open()
Get-IssuesForVersion $conn "Version XYZ"
$conn.close()
$timeend = $(Get-Date) 
$duration = $timeend - $timestart # first run: approx 30 seconds

$timestart = $(Get-Date)
$conn = Get-SQLConnection
$conn.open()
Get-IssuesForVersion $conn "Version XYZ"
$conn.close()
$timeend = $(Get-Date) 
$duration = $timeend - $timestart # second run: approx 2 seconds
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: You already know the answer, is it important to know which effects are the cause: hdd-cache, file system cache, db.cache?

Comment: yes it'd be nice, for optimization, - and just known where and how to pull the knobs to manually improve performance ;-) (will look if I creating indices/views will help on the oracle side...)

Comment: Where are you running the script from? The console or ISE? The PowerShell ISE will save script variables and the console does not.

Comment: @LotPings. You may well be right; but it would be much better to determine the answer by getting diagnostics or trace information. For SQL issues, you need (preferably a SQL Monitor report or) runtime execution plan

Comment: You are doing more than one this during this time frame. Do yourself a favour and use `Measure-Command` and check for each individual function/action you are doing. That should tell you where the biggest change is coming from.

Comment: @BobC - can you recommend a SQL remote performance monitoring tool?

Comment: @Matt - it's the execution of the SQL query / can also reproduce the time difference with SQLDeveloper